# What is wrong with my code to retrieve email info from firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to include a "Welcome, (email id)" label in the screen that shows up one a user has been authenticated and registered/logged in. However, with the following code, I am unable to retrieve this:

```
func loadUserData() {
    guard let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { print("SHSHS")
        return
    }
    Database.database().reference().child("users").childByAutoId().child("email").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {
            print("shdgufr")
            return }
        print(username)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    loadUserData()
}
```

error thrown is :

Listener at /users/(insert current users unique id)/email failed: permission_denied

Comment: Set breakpoints and single-step through your code. Do any of your `guard`s trigger?

Comment: no they do not, I've changed the code and updated the error it throws, please do have a look I you can

Comment: Your database rules doesnt allow the operation, add your database rules

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. `.childByAutoId` is used when *creating* a node and you want to generate a new 'random' key for the node. Also, if you want to query for a node that contains an email, that's not how you do it - you would need a Firebase Query for that. However, it looks like you may be storing your users in a /users node by their uid. If that's the case you don't need a query at all, you can access the node directly.

Comment: Also note that, even if it was corrected, the code is reading a node `/email` but then printing `username` which doesn't go together.

Comment: If you are using password authentication then the user would have to enter their email to log in, right? So you would already have their email - along those same lines, if they authenticate you can get their email from the Auth properties with `let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email`. Perhaps you are authenticating some other way or maybe you mean to get a custom username or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP is asking how to read user data from a users node. If we assume the Firebase structure is like this

```
users
   uid_0 //the users uid
      name: "Peter"
      email: "peter@something.com"
   uid_1
      name: "Ralph"
      email: "ralph@test.com"
```

the code to read Peter's node is

```
    let peterRef = self.ref.child("users").child("uid_0")
    peterRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No name"
        let email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String ?? "No email"
        print(name, email)
    })
```

where I have a class var `self.ref` that points to my Firebase.

Comment: This helped me understand, thank you

Answer (score -1):

To get the user's email:

```
let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
```

Comment: The op is trying to retrieve a username from Firebase `print(username)` which he is attempting to look up by a given email address. He's not asking how to get the email address.